# Basis for Forwards

Tags: futures, forward, basis

Does the concept of a "Basis" for a forward based product make sense, or is it only ever explicitly for Futures? I understand the concept could mean the Forward Spot - Spot, but am not aware if makes sense from a business perspective in equity trade. and cannot query traders.

Comment: Futures and forwards are essentially the same thing, just listed vs OTC. In fact forward points are basis points that are added or subtracted to the spot rate. There is a minor difference in terms of pricing due to unpredictable rates but that's unimportant here.